# RegEx looking both backwards and forward

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to get all the strings when it has a given term not followed by a set of given terms either preceded by the same terms using regular expressions, something like this:

```
(?<!(term1|term2)[\w\- ]{1,25})my_term(?![\w\- ]{1,25}(term1|term2))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Visualisation](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8OTCmRELoXx4mQ9w)

but it seems it doesn't work with any of the following texts:

```
my_term good example.
Another good my_term example.
This one term1 shouldn't my_term work.
Neither my_term do term2 it.
```

Any idea?

Comment: It can be work around with optional capturing group, see https://ideone.com/qVcdt6. Note that `[\w\- ]` does not match `'`, you should either reconsider this part of the pattern or just add it as I did in the code demo.

Comment: Please explain: What do you want to match, when do you want it to match. When not.

Comment: Better answer: what is the expected result for the text you supplied?

Comment: Python `re` module doesn't support variable length lookbehinds. Your regex should throw a syntax error.

Comment: Also, check [this demo](https://ideone.com/2b2i0p), do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `re` module doesn't support variable length lookbehinds. Your regex should throw a syntax error. A workaround would be using tempered dots:

```
^(?:(?!term1|term2).)*my_term(?:(?!term1|term2).)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lfCXWF/1)

Answer (score 1):

Variable look behind is not supported in RegEx.

```
    (?<!(term1|term2)**[\w\- ]{1,25}**)my_term(?![\w\- ]{1,25}(term1|term2))
```

The part I have marked with  ** ** ie [\w- ]**{1,25}** is variable in the look behind group.

Can you give the input and expected output for a more specific answer?